# How to restore configurations files ? (SNMP)

Tags: linux, command-line, snmp

I wanted to know what should I do to restore the configuration files if I've modified or accidentally deleted a file.

In my case, I'm talking about `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`, what command should I use to reinstall it?

Comment: I've found [this](https://elkano.org/blog/reinstall-restore-deleted-config-files-debian-ubuntu/). So according to that site, if you are on Debian-based distro  you could use `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall snmpd`

Comment: Thanks, it works !

Comment: @EdgarMagallon please post the answer bellow, i'll then be able to mark the question as anwered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For restoring the  configuration files you can use:

```bash
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall packagename
```

So in this case the command (for `snmpd`) would be:

```bash
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall snmpd
```

Credits [to this site](https://elkano.org/blog/reinstall-restore-deleted-config-files-debian-ubuntu/)